# Authlogic remember_me on signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

We want to have remember_me enabled when the user signs up. When logging in its really easy to do this, how do to we do this on signup though, as we're literally only creating a User object?

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing something like this after user creation (worked for me):

```
current_user_session.remember_me = true
current_user_session.save
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the user is logged in automatically once his account is created.
Make sure that when you create a session for him for the first time you just pass remember_me as true:

```
UserSession.create(claimed_user, :remember_me => true)
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to help:

     # Create the User
      @user = User.new
      ...
      @user.save
      @user_session = UserSession.new(@user, :remember_me => true)

As soon as the user closes their browser they are logged out.